# Blockchain and ReactJs UI

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum

I have to make a blockchain project but I don't have too much time to spare on the ui,
so can i use the readymade dashboard templates, although I don't require them all and need only three page ui.
Will using a template take more time to actually organize the related complications or actually save time of creating a UI.

Comment: In that case just use a simple single page template and convert it to different components as per your requirements and you are good to start with this template

Comment: The template is easy but sometimes it will need more time understanding where it is or where to edit. Or else try giving it to some freelancers.

Answer (score 0):

0x protocol and dydx protocol are the best readymade templates for trading and margin-trading platforms with dashboard.

https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit-frontend

https://github.com/dydxprotocol

You can start work by forking these repositories.